# CLI Resize ends with "Killed"

Tags: product-images, magento2.3.4, cli, resize

I'm trying to resize all the images in my 2.3.4 Magento database. I have about 100 images to resize.

When I run the command line instruction, bin/magento catalog:images:resize , it comes back with a message when amost done that it is killed.

Is this a memory issue? Is this a processing issue? A time issue? I would like to do the rest of the images. Is there a way to start the resize at the 50% completed mark or ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the command with dmemory_limit as below.

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

Comment: Well, it got to about 92% (instead of 89%) but then I got the same error. Is there a way to individually resize the image files in Magento? At this point, I'd be happy to do that.

Comment: @JeffreyMarks Try Updated answer

Comment: Still having trouble with it. Is there a way on the command line to resize a single image? I'd be willing to do that as I only have a few images left to process?